# Tem como melhorar

Tags: c

Bom ter como melhorar? acredito que sim.
Mas melhorar o que? o código deixa-lo mais leve, melhorar desempenho essas coisas. gostaria de dicas e pois estou estudando ainda. Vou postar abaixo 3 códigos de vetores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//cria um vetor de 10 posições e imprime somente números primos.
//minha impressão não esta nada legal e quando abro outro for os dados do vetor mudam.

int main()
{
    int num[9], i, j;
    int cont=0;

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        printf("\ndigite 9 numeros:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);

        for(j=1; j<=num[i]; j++)
        {
            if(num[i]%j==0)
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        if(cont==2)
            printf("\nvetor[%d]:%d\n", i+1, num[i]);
        cont=0;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

=======================================================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10];
    int i, j, k, n1=0, n2=0, aux=0;


    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
    }

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    i=j=0;
    for(k=0;k<=9;k++)//Intercala os vetores
    {
        rvet[k]=k%2==0 ? vet1[i++] : vet2[j++];

        printf("vet[%d]:%d\n", k, rvet[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

=======================================================================

esse ordena dois vetores de 5 posições e em um outro vetor de forma decrescente.
acredito que esse não há muito o que se preocupar mas deem uma olhada quem sabe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10];
    int i, j, k, l, m, n1=0, n2=0, aux=0;


    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%d", &vet1[i]);
    }

    fflush(stdin);//limpar sujeira  
    system("cls");//limpar a tela

    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet2:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }

    fflush(stdin);//limpar sujeira
    system("cls");//limpar a tela


    for(k=0; k<=4; k++)//preenche as 5 primeiras posições com vet1;
    {
        rvet[k]=vet1[k];
    }

    for(k=5; k<=9; k++)//preenche as 5 ultimas posições com vet2
    {
        rvet[k]=vet2[k-5];
    }   

    //gera a ordenação dos elementos do rvet
    for(l=0; l<=9; l++)//pega elemento por elemento em sua posição original.
    {
        for(m=l+1; m<=9; m++)//pega o elemento da posição seguinte
        {
            if(rvet[m]>rvet[l])//se o proximo numero for maior...
            {
                aux=rvet[m];//guarda ele em aux
                rvet[m]=rvet[l];//rvet[1] troca por numero maior
                rvet[l]=aux;//e numero menor fica guardado na fila(aux)
            }
            //numero do aux ou o ultimo da fila eh guardado em rvet[9]
        }
    }

    for(k=0; k<=9; k++)//imprime
    {
        printf("%d\n", rvet[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: exercício de faculdade né?
Li só o primeiro dos números primos, fora o 2 nenhum outro par é primero, nenhum múltiplo de 5, então tu consegue otimizar

Comment: Avaliação é aqui: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok obrigado irei deixar mais dois dias a postagem ja que me responderam aqui porem irei fazer uma la tambem @PapaCharlie

Answer (score 3):

Desempenho de numeros primos:

1. nao precisas de ver se é multiplo de 1 nem de si próprio; no fim verificas se o total de divisores é `0` (em vez de `2`).
2. não precisas de verificar divisores inferiores à raiz quadrada do número (por exemplo para `33` (raiz quadrada == `5.74...`) só precisas de verificar se é múltiplo de `2`, `3`, e `5`).
3. Assim que encontrares um divisor podes sair do ciclo porque o número é composto (para `33`, assim que verificas que é múltiplo de `3` já não precisas de verificar se é múltiplo de `5`)
4. Trata o `2` como caso especial e vai aumentado os divisores de `2` em `2` (`2`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `9`, `11`, ...). `for (j = 3; j < LIMITE, j += 2)`
5. Expandindo o caso 4, podes tratar `2` e `3` como casos especiais e verificar os divisores do forma `6*k ± 1`.
6. Como vais tratar vários números no mesmo programa, podes guardar os primos que fores encontrando num array, e testar apenas se esses números são divisores para os testes posteriores.

Diverte-te!

Comment: +1 Pontos muito interessantes

Comment: massa @pmg irei dar uma olhada =)